# Como accedo mediante fetch a un array dentro de la respuesta?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, get

Estoy haciendo un programa básico para leer unos parámetros de una api rest (estoy empezando) y quiero leer dentro de la respuesta que me da el fetch uno de los apartados que es un elemento de un array, os muestro.

Este es mi código(en la consola muestro toda la respuesta para revisarla)

```
.then(data => {
  return data.json();
  })
  .then(post => {  
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML=post.variables.path;
  console.log(post);
  });
```

Y esta es la respuesta que me da en la consola, yo quiero mostrar el elemento del array:
[image: ``````]

Comment: Por ahora hay un único elemento en el array pero en caso de haber más ¿cuál de ellos es al que quieres acceder? ¿será siempre el primero?

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores mi intención es mostrar ese elemento y a poder ser en concreto su valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso y tal y como comentas que solo quieres recibir ese valor podrías acceder a él haciendo:

```
post.variables[0].value; // <-- Valor

post.variables[0].path; // <-- Path
```

Si el elemento devolviese más items dentro del array tendrías que filtrarlos para obtener uno, coger siempre solo el primero o bien pintarlos todos de alguna otra forma pero por el momento para lo que pides serviría con eso.

Comment: si almaceno la respuesta en una variable así: valor = post.variables[0].value; que tipo de variable sería? String?

Comment: depende de que devuelva la API. En este caso el tipo será Boolean, puesto que el `post.variables[0].value` es `false`.