# Actualizar un valor de un array en una api

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch

Estoy tratando de modificar el valor que anteriormente conseguí en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537548/como-accedo-mediante-fetch-a-un-array-dentro-de-la-respuesta/537549?noredirect=1#comment952556_537549) y no lo consigo, sospecho que mi sintaxis no es la mejor.

```
const body_on ={
  "variables":
  [
    {
      "path": "Arp.Plc.Eclr/bPrueba",
      "value": true,
    }
  ]
}
function escribir_on(){
  fetch(base_url,{
    method: 'PUT',
    body: body_on
  })
}
```

Comment: la propiedad `body` ha de ser algo *serializable* por Javascript, prueba a usar `JSON.stringify(body_on)`

Comment: El resultado de tu pregunta anterior, era una solicitud POST? Es que el alcance de nombres entre "postear" una pregunta me confunde. Más bien pienso que era una solicitud GET a `base_url`, o me equivoco?

Comment: Creo que sería mejor [edit] esta pregunta y sustituir "post" por "pregunta" :P

Comment: @ffflabs si, fue una solicitud get

Comment: @PabloLozano me sirvió lo que me dijiste y perdón por expresarme mal.